# If i set Views filter for Country, should the exposed State filter be limited to just the states of the chosen country/ies?

Tags: drupal-views, addresses

On a D7 civi 4.6.x site on a CiviContact View I set up Country filter set to US (not exposed) and set State to Exposed.
Result was the exposed State filter only shows 'any' and did not give any options of actual States.

I retested by exposing the Country filter too, set to only US, but again same outcome.

Should this be working as I hope given this [jira issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-12462) is resolved, ie if a Country filter is set to a specific country (whether exposed or not) and if the State filter is set to exposed, then I should only see the States pertaining to the selected country?

I also checked the options if i edit the State filter, just to confirm the filtering to US only states wasn't happening there and that I then needed to select them all to show)

Here is the query

```
SELECT civicrm_contact.id AS id, civicrm_contact.display_name AS civicrm_contact_display_name, civicrm_address2.state_province_id AS civicrm_address2_state_province_id
FROM 
{civicrm_contact} civicrm_contact
LEFT JOIN {civicrm_address} civicrm_address ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_address.contact_id
LEFT JOIN {civicrm_address} civicrm_address2 ON civicrm_contact.id = civicrm_address2.contact_id AND civicrm_address2.is_primary = '1'
WHERE (( (civicrm_contact.display_name LIKE '%]%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (civicrm_contact.display_name LIKE '%Affiliate%' ESCAPE '\\') AND (civicrm_address.country_id  = 1228) ))
```

Comment: I am also seeing this but unsure if it is related: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in civicrm_handler_filter_state_multi->get_value_options() (line 55 of ../sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/modules/views/civicrm/civicrm_handler_filter_state_multi.inc).